# How to add Phylotree.js to nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, d3.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I installed phylotreejs using the following command:
`npm install --save phylotree`

When I try to import this into a page like this:

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import phylotree from 'phylotree/build/phylotree';
```

I get the following error:

```
Cannot read property 'phylotree' of undefined
```

It would be really helpful if I can understand what's going on here.
I read and tried the following things by reading nuxt documentation [https://nuxtjs.org/faq/]

```
import phylotree from '~/node_modules/phylotree/build/phylotree.js'
```

```
export default {
  head () {
    return {
      script: [
        { src: '~/node_modules/phylotree/build/phylotree.js' }
      ],
    }
  },
}
```

but nothing seems to work

Following is the Vue page, I'm trying to create:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <section class="section">
      <div class="container">
        <div id="phylotree"></div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import phylotree from 'phylotree';
import _ from 'lodash';

export default {
  data:() => ({
    example_tree : "(((EELA:0.150276,CONGERA:0.213019):0.230956,(EELB:0.263487,CONGERB:0.202633):0.246917):0.094785,((CAVEFISH:0.451027,(GOLDFISH:0.340495,ZEBRAFISH:0.390163):0.220565):0.067778,((((((NSAM:0.008113,NARG:0.014065):0.052991,SPUN:0.061003,(SMIC:0.027806,SDIA:0.015298,SXAN:0.046873):0.046977):0.009822,(NAUR:0.081298,(SSPI:0.023876,STIE:0.013652):0.058179):0.091775):0.073346,(MVIO:0.012271,MBER:0.039798):0.178835):0.147992,((BFNKILLIFISH:0.317455,(ONIL:0.029217,XCAU:0.084388):0.201166):0.055908,THORNYHEAD:0.252481):0.061905):0.157214,LAMPFISH:0.717196,((SCABBARDA:0.189684,SCABBARDB:0.362015):0.282263,((VIPERFISH:0.318217,BLACKDRAGON:0.109912):0.123642,LOOSEJAW:0.397100):0.287152):0.140663):0.206729):0.222485,(COELACANTH:0.558103,((CLAWEDFROG:0.441842,SALAMANDER:0.299607):0.135307,((CHAMELEON:0.771665,((PIGEON:0.150909,CHICKEN:0.172733):0.082163,ZEBRAFINCH:0.099172):0.272338):0.014055,((BOVINE:0.167569,DOLPHIN:0.157450):0.104783,ELEPHANT:0.166557):0.367205):0.050892):0.114731):0.295021)",
  }),
  mounted (){
    // const phylotree = require('phylotree');
    var tree = d3.layout.phylotree()
                 .svg(d3.select("#phylotree"));
    tree(example_tree).layout();
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
#spaced {
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}
.section {
  padding: 1.5rem 1.5rem;
}
</style>
```

Comment: If you did all of the above, you should be able to import the module using: `const phylotree = require('phylotree)'`. This is from their docs: http://phylotree.hyphy.org/documentation/intro.html#installation
`import phylotree from 'phylotree'` might also work.

Comment: @LupuȘtefanAlex I tried ```const phylotree = require('phylotree')``` as you pointed out, but it doesn't seem to work. Still showing me error in ```var tree = d3.layout.phylotree()```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out what was going on. The d3 version for phylotree.js is v3 while I was using v5. But even then it didn't work. So, I tried it in a simple html file and found out the requirements as  in this page [Link](http://phylotree.hyphy.org/examples/hello-world/).
Then tried the following script, it worked. But is there a better way to do this. Can anyone help me figure this out!

```
<template>
  <section class="section">
    <div class="container">
      <svg id="tree_display" />
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  head () {
    return {
      script: [
        { src: 'https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js' },
        { src: 'https://veg.github.io/phylotree.js/phylotree.js' },
        { src: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js' },
      ],
    }
  },
  mounted (){
    var example_tree = "(((EELA:0.150276,CONGERA:0.213019):0.230956,(EELB:0.263487,CONGERB:0.202633):0.246917):0.094785,((CAVEFISH:0.451027,(GOLDFISH:0.340495,ZEBRAFISH:0.390163):0.220565):0.067778,((((((NSAM:0.008113,NARG:0.014065):0.052991,SPUN:0.061003,(SMIC:0.027806,SDIA:0.015298,SXAN:0.046873):0.046977):0.009822,(NAUR:0.081298,(SSPI:0.023876,STIE:0.013652):0.058179):0.091775):0.073346,(MVIO:0.012271,MBER:0.039798):0.178835):0.147992,((BFNKILLIFISH:0.317455,(ONIL:0.029217,XCAU:0.084388):0.201166):0.055908,THORNYHEAD:0.252481):0.061905):0.157214,LAMPFISH:0.717196,((SCABBARDA:0.189684,SCABBARDB:0.362015):0.282263,((VIPERFISH:0.318217,BLACKDRAGON:0.109912):0.123642,LOOSEJAW:0.397100):0.287152):0.140663):0.206729):0.222485,(COELACANTH:0.558103,((CLAWEDFROG:0.441842,SALAMANDER:0.299607):0.135307,((CHAMELEON:0.771665,((PIGEON:0.150909,CHICKEN:0.172733):0.082163,ZEBRAFINCH:0.099172):0.272338):0.014055,((BOVINE:0.167569,DOLPHIN:0.157450):0.104783,ELEPHANT:0.166557):0.367205):0.050892):0.114731):0.295021)";

    var tree = d3.layout.phylotree()
                 .svg(d3.select("#tree_display"));

    tree(example_tree).layout();

  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
#spaced {
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}
.section {
  padding: 1.5rem 1.5rem;
}
</style>
```